# .htaccess rewrite rule - can't fetch second parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just started to play around with .htaccess in order to make my URLs look nice.

The first rewriterule below works fine: **example.com/user/100** calls **example.com/index.php?p=profile&user=100** just like it should.

The second one however does not work the way I want it to. For some reason I can't fetch the $2 parameter. I want **example.com/discussion/1873/iehf8383** to redirect to **example.com/index.php?p=discussion&id=1873&token=iehf8383**

Here's the .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^user/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?p=profile&user=$1
RewriteRule ^discussion/(\d+)/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?p=discussion&id=$1&token=$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `\d` matches a digit, your example will not match the second rule.  Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^quiz/(\d+)/([\w\d]+) ./index.php?p=discussion&id=$1&token=$2
```

This will allow your token to contain any alpha-numeric character, rather than limiting to just digits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, however I still get a 404. My token can contain 0-9 a-z A-Z. Does your rule allow capitals? Something is still strange, no idea what it is.

Comment: Would you mind posting your solution?  I can update my answer if it is not correct (want to make sure the content here is useful).

Comment: It was me messing up with something else, your answer was perfectly correct, it solved my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
RewriteRule ^quiz/(\d+)/(\d+)*$ ./index.php?p=discussion&id=$1&token=$2
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^quiz/(\d+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?p=discussion&id=$1&token=$2
```